# Cannot disable LiveReloading webapck dev server for my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

hers my webpack config which i used for my project.

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");
const DotenvPlugin = require('webpack-dotenv-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true,
    port: 8080,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      .........
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new DotenvPlugin({
      sample: './.env',
      path: './.env'
    }),
    //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ]
};
```

here is my script from package.json file

```
"app-start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.config.js --open",
```

even after adding this

```
"app-start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.config.js --no-inline --no-hot --open",
```

it doesnt work.

I've also tried putting the hot:false within the webpack config file yet it still reloades the project on save of code.

am i doing something wrong yes please correct.

Answer (score 3):

I understood that you want to avoid the live reload of the application once you do any changes in your code base.

so please try the below config , It might help.

```
devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true,
noInfo: true,
overlay: true,
port: 8080,
host: '0.0.0.0',
disableHostCheck: true,
hot: false,
inline: false
```

}

make sure you have ejected the webpack using 'npm run eject'.

Comment: what should i write in eject script in package.json 
im not usng create-react-app ive configured the webapck manually

Answer (score 2):

Running the server with `webpack-dev-server --liveReload false` could help I believe.

Comment: nowadays it's `--no-live-reload`

Answer (score 1):

It worked Now I changed the run script to :

```
    "app-start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.config.js --no-inline",
```